# Its tell missing right parenthessis

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGES 
(
     ChrgCode CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
     ChrgDescription NVARCHAR(80) NOTNULL,
     Duration NUMBER(2) NOTNULL (DURATION <= 60),
     HourlyRate NUMBER(3) (HourlyRate <= 399)
)
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, Welcome to the community. In order to help you, we would need additional details like error message and also is it MS Sql Server or MySQL? By just looking at the syntax there are multiple issues, `NOTNULL`, `DURATION <=60` and `HourlyRate <=399` seem to be wrong. Also please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: don't use the `char` type. It has a lot of problems and offers no advantages whatsoever over `varchar`

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work,

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGES (
    ChrgCode CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
    ChrgDescription NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Duration NUMBER(2) NOT NULL check (Duration <=60),
    HourlyRate NUMBER(3) check(HourlyRate <=399) 
)
```

The reason that it has syntax error in OP's case is that the missing `check` keyword. (I assume the missing blank between NOT and NULL are copy / paste errors).

As pointed out in the comment, yes, varchar2 and nvarchar2 should be preferred these days.

Comment: This looks correct, assuming the database is Oracle, so it does not deserve to be downvoted.  That said, the answer should probably have a bit of explanation and should point out that `varchar2()` and `nvarchar2()` are the preferred data types.